# How to build Baseline model to predict Y with multiple values using skLearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a sample data frame that looks like below. I would like to build a baseline model to predict `y_combined` using `X=df.filter(regex='x_')`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x_1':[0.1,0.2,0.1,0],
    'x_2':[0.5,0.1,0.3,0.4],
    'x_3':[0.2,0.1,0.6,0.1],
    'x_4':[0,0.5,0.2,0.3],
    'y_1': [0, 1, 1, 0],
    'y_2': [0, 0, 1, 0],
    'y_3': [0, 1, 0, 1],
    'y_combined': [np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([1, 0, 1]),
                   np.array([1, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1])]
})
```

[image]

I am new to the baseline model building. To obtain `y_predicted`, how should I specify the DummyClassifer() model with `strategy="constant"`? Or is there a different strategy I should be using?

For example, if the `y_predicted = [1,1,1]`, then I will see how well the prediction model performs by getting the average centroid between `y_combined` and `y_predicted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your question under the premise that you want to use the [`DummyClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html#sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier) using the `strategy='constant'` setting to build a baseline model for a multilabel classification problem, where the output equals `y_combined` of `df`. In this case, the following code will work:

```py
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


X = pd.DataFrame({
    'x_1': [0.1,0.2,0.1,0],
    'x_2': [0.5,0.1,0.3,0.4],
    'x_3': [0.2,0.1,0.6,0.1],
    'x_4': [0,0.5,0.2,0.3]
})
y = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

clf = DummyClassifier(strategy='constant', constant=np.array([1, 1, 1]))
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Notice that when you use `strategy='constant'` you also have to state the constant value that should be predicted via the `constant=...` parameter of the `DummyClassifier`. You will see that the baseline model will now always predict the specified constant value, no matter the input:

```py
y_pred = clf.predict(X)
print(y_pred)

# output
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Since you also asked about other strategies, you can basically choose any of the strategies mentioned in the documentation of [`DummyClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html#sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier). All have a common behaviour, as mentioned in the user guide:

> Note that with all these strategies, the predict method completely ignores the input data!

Comment: Thanks so much! Since my actual data has 48 Y columns, I set the constant=np.full(
  shape=48,
  fill_value=1,
  dtype=np.int
) However, this gave me an error "Constant target value should have shape (1, 1).""

Comment: Nothing wrong with the way you set the constant. The error message but indicates that the shape of your array with the target values (`y` in the example) is `(1, 1)`, unlike the constant value which apparently has `(48,)`. You have to align the shape of the array with the target values and the shape of the constant. Then it will work.